# Boton inicio de sesion Google Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

Buenas noches,

Estoy utilizando el boton de inicio de sesion de google para android estudio pero me arroja el siguiente error y no logro encontrar la solucion[image: error]

quien me pueda ayudar mil gracias!

Comment: Cumples con todos los requisitos para integrar la API de google ?

Comment: Hola ya me funciono